# Struts2 cannot use validation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

Please pardon since I am very new to Struts2.

I created a very simple form and I've created the following LoginAction-validation.xml:

```
<validators>
  <field name="username">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
      <message key="username.required"/>    
   </field-validator>
    </field>
       <field name="password">
     <field-validator type="requiredstring">
     <message key="password.required"/> 
   </field-validator>  
  </field>
</validators>
```

I have put this xml file under WEB-INF/classes. When I run the jsp page and left the username and password field empty, I won't get a warning message but redirected me to the error.jsp.

I've looked at the console, and it showed there were some warnings during the process:

```
 WARNING: Parameter [username] is not on the excludeParams list of patterns and will be appended to action!
 WARNING: Parameter [password] is not on the excludeParams list of patterns and will be appended to action!
```

I suspect maybe I had put the validation.xml in the wrong folder, but I am not sure where is the correct place. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem was your `validation.xml` is not correctly placed.

Means don't put validation.xml files in `web-inf/classes` folder instead put in the

action package where your action class is present.

For eg: for the some action class your package name is `com.insert` and `your class name is`

`Insert.java` & your validation file must be in the `same pacakge` with the name

`Insert-validation.xml` then it will work correctly.

```
Bottom Line Is:action class and validation file should be present in a same package.
```

Comment: thanks. However, I am using Eclipse and placed the Action class under the default package.Thus, I placed my validation.xml into the "build/classes" folder where I see all the compiled action classes. Again, no luck. Could you give me some suggestions? Thx

Comment: My suggestion is: When anyone new to struts or learning struts go with the struts-blank.war file. Why because every thing(library files) including Directory Structure is present correctly under the web content start with new jsp page and you won't get confused.Take this link it is very helpful and take only from this directory struts-blank.war file import directly to your eclipse and start doing the project.

Answer (score 1):

Validation xml file must be in the same Java package as action class it validates.
In your war file `LoginAction-validation.xml` file should be inside `WEB-INF/classes/your_loginAction_package`.

Answer (score 1):

As said in AleksandrM answer, every action-validation.xml file must be in the same place of the correspondant Action.

An exception is made for the Visitor Validator, where the object-validation.xml file must be in the same folder of the object you are validating, that is not an Action.

Some info:

- you must define an INPUT result for your Action,
- when your fields raises one or more validation errors, your Action method (eg. execute()) is not reached (only prepare() method, if present, is executed), so if you have some population to be done always, like combobox loading, use prepare() or session;
- to view the errors in the JSP, you need to put the tag `<s:fielderror />` in it.